# Can't reindex Magento 2 on MAMP through OSX terminal

Tags: magento2, mamp

I'm trying reindex latest Magento 2 using OSX 10.11 terminal with `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` command without success. Terminal returns same error on two red blocks.

[image]

– Maybe MYSQL socket problem?

ps. Magento2 is setup on MAMP PRO 3.

Answer (score 0):

this is the same problem that is happening here:

[MAMP Errors for Magento Command Line](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/168224/mamp-errors-for-magento-command-line)

With the solution being found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262006/how-to-use-mamps-version-of-php-instead-of-the-default-on-osx#answer-26561760

I just had to put this line in my .bash_profile. If you don't have one, just make one under your user.

> vi ~/.bash_profile

And then add in this line, paying attention to the version of php that you are running.

```
# MAMP PHP
export MAMP_PHP=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.22/bin
export PATH="$MAMP_PHP:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mamp go to the root directory where Magento is installed and type php in front of the command.
ex:

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Answer (score -1):

first command:  `php bin/magento cache:flush`

second command: `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

working 100%