# MAMP Errors for Magento Command Line

Tags: magento2, mamp, local

When I run static content deploy on my local Magento2 instance I get this error message:

```
[PDOException]                                    
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

Is this a etc/hosts and/or virtual hosts issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a combination of issues. This article outlines the problem you are having:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/trouble/php/tshoot_phpini.html

And this goes over how to fix it:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262006/how-to-use-mamps-version-of-php-instead-of-the-default-on-osx#answer-26561760

While there are a few different ways to fix this, i have linked to the one solution that i have used.